# Cactivedataprovider with pagination

Tags: php, yii, pagination

Firstly, here we have more records in table, so that we want to add pagination in page and the code goes as here

```
    public function actionCompany()
        {
              $model = new CompanyProfile();
              $criteria1 = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria1->addCondition('cmpny_profile_id=-1');
            $dataProvidernew= new CActiveDataProvider('CompanyProfile',array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria1,'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>10),
        ));
       if(isset($_POST['CompanyProfile'])){
                $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
                $model->cmpny_profile_name = $_POST['CompanyProfile']['cmpny_profile_name'];
                if(!empty($model->cmpny_profile_name))
                {
        $criteria->addSearchCondition('cmpny_profile_name', $model->cmpny_profile_name);

                }
      $dataProvidernew= new CActiveDataProvider('CompanyProfile',array(
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>10),

                ));
            }
        $this->render('company',array('model'=>$model,'dataProvider'=>$dataProvidernew));
    }
```

Now, on loading the page, no records will be displayed and we have a form to submit in page.So on submitting the form, the code displays the first 10 records fine. When we click on the second link of pagination no records will be showing.
My question is that, on clicking the second link of pagination, the form is submitting but the value `$model->cmpny_profile_name` is empty, so the code has to display the 10 records but not showing single ,why? Please let us know the reason.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Cactivedataprovider with pagination doesnot load the page, pagination works with ajax.So if you echo the code in if condition , you can check through ajax no data will be displayed.So on clicking second link of pagination, same page with pagination will be loaded with ajax and `cmpny_profile_id=-1` condition will be applied and no form has submitted so no data will be displayed.